# Add users to a Security Group in active directory

Tags: .net, vb.net, active-directory

**Using any .NET framework**

I am able to create security groups, however when I try to add users from within the same domain I get an error.

Using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`:

```
TheGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(SecurityContext, "GROUPNAME")
TheGroup.Members.Add(SecurityContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "username")
TheGroup.Save()
```

Everything works for creating, and getting an existing group. Also adding the members works but when I try to save the changes made to the group I get this error:

> Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355).

Now doing it without using `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`:

```
Dim dGroup As DirectoryEntry = GetDirectoryEntry(GroupPath, UserName, Password)
dGroup.Properties("member").Add(nUser.Path)
dGroup.CommitChanges()
dGroup.Close()
```

Again creating/deleting groups this way is working fine, however when I try to add a member that DOES exist to the a created group I get this error:

> The server is unwilling to process the request. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072035)

**Going onto the server running AD itself and I can add groups and place users in them. I am using the same credentials.**

Comment: **Update**
If i Add the user manually to the SG i want to and than try in .NET to add that same user it will say it already exists. But if i remove the user than try to add him in .NET i get the error again. "Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355)."

:(

Comment: **Update** Now when i add a user manually and than try to remove them in .NET and when i commit the changes it has a problem. Im guessing this may be some type of permission problems from remote entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh, i fixed my problem.

I was working on this on my prod workstation connecting to the 1 of our dev AD servers. I than decided to run the project from my dev workstation and everything worked fine.

Comment: Whenever you find the solution to a problem it is always so simple.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess: You may get this error because the user you are trying to add to the security group does not have a password that follows your password policy for the domain.

Comment: Unfortunately ive created users directly to the OU im adding the SG's too manually, so they did conform to the password policy and i still couldnt add them to the group.

Comment: Are you using LDAP and not GC or something?